# Bootstrap modal button click not firing with click event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am using a bootastrap modal inside a .Net MVC Razor page which uses Vue JS
The modal popup is initiated with a button click event like below

```
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn"  v-on:click="rejectModal(item)">Reject Popup</button> 
</div>


rejectModal: function (item) {
  this.selectedItemReject = item; //set a property 
  console.log(this.selectedItemReject);
  $('#declineModal').modal('show'); //show modal
},
```

This shows the popup and text area to enter a comment and when i am trying to click on SAVE Button , The click event seems to be not firing.  I am planning to add the notes property to selectedItemReject  object and proceed with an ajax call and hide popup on SAVE button click.  But no idea why the button click event is firing

```
<div class="modal fade" id="declineModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="declineModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="declineModalLabel">Decline Note</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <textarea name="decline-notes" v-model="rejectNote" placeholder="Add a note..."  rows="4" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button  class="btn btn-primary"  v-on:click="reject">SAVE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



reject: function () {
  console.log("reject"); // NOT FIRING 
  }
```

Based on some suggestions already tried removing data-dismiss="modal" from close button , but no differece

Comment: The code looks good. You can check for errors in console. Also make sure to create build and hard refresh your browser to invalidate cache.

Comment: The reason is that the modal DIV is outside the scope of VueJS App . Vue JS app is defined for a root div and  i moved the modal div to inside that and everything working again